# Android / Firebase Error: Lifecycle owner is attempting to register while current state ist RESUMED / Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, deprecated

I am trying to use Firebase authentification to implement a Google SignIn for my Android app.

The suggested method was as follows:

```
    private fun signInGoogle() {
        val signInIntent: Intent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result ->
            onActivityResult(Req_Code, result, signInIntent)
        }
    }

    private fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, result: ActivityResult, data:Intent) {
        if (requestCode == Req_Code) {
            val task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            handleResult(task)
        }
    }
```

With onActivityResult deprecated, I tried to substitute with registerForActivityResult. My onCreate now looks like this:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)

        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("token stuff")
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        Signin.setOnClickListener { view: View? ->
            Toast.makeText(this, "Logging In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            val signInIntent: Intent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent

            getResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){
                if(it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                    val task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(signInIntent)
                    handleResult(task)
                }
            }
            getResult.launch(signInIntent)
        }
    }
```

While I get no compiler error, at runtime I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleOwner mypackage.MainActivity@850d108 is attempting to register while current state is RESUMED. LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED.
```

Can someone please help fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: So why are you calling `registerForActivityResult` inside your `setOnClickListener` and not registering as part of your `onCreate()`, like the error message says you need to do?

Comment: If you need to implement Firebase sign-in with Google on Android, you should consider using the information in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) where it is explained how to use One Tap. Here you can find a useful [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d).

Comment: @ianhanniballake - thank you! That fixed it! I mistakenly considered the setOnClickListener as a part of onCreate!